# Eclipse C/C++ CDT annoying issue

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Each time I am programming in eclipse it shows me when I clean all projects:

> Cleaning all projects has encountered a problem. Errors occured during the build.
>
> "Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Working'.
>   Internal error building project Working configuration Debug
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Could not delete '/Working/Debug'.
>   Could not delete '/Working/Debug'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   Could not delete: C:\Users\Asus\workspace\Working\Debug.
>   Internal error building project Working configuration Debug
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Could not delete '/Working/Debug'.
>   Could not delete '/Working/Debug'.
>   Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   Could not delete: C:\Users\Asus\workspace\Working\Debug. "

This is shown to me in the problems tab near console: **"cannot open output file Working.exe: Permission denied"**

And when I hit run it shows me this: **"Launching working.exe has encountered a problem. The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist."**

And in the log file the one within the metadata folder it said this:

> Contains: Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   Contains: Could not delete: C:\Users\Asus\workspace\Working\Debug.
>   !SUBENTRY 4 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 273 2014-09-08 21:25:22.006
>   !MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting resources.
>   !SUBENTRY 5 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 273 2014-09-08 21:25:22.006
>   !MESSAGE Problems encountered while deleting files.
>   !SUBENTRY 6 org.eclipse.core.filesystem 4 273 2014-09-08 21:25:22.006
>   !MESSAGE Could not delete: C:\Users\Asus\workspace\Working\Debug.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core 4 104 2014-09-08 21:26:00.448
>   !MESSAGE The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist
>   !STACK 0
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Asus\workspace\Working\Debug\Working.exe not found
>   at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.CDebugUtils.verifyProgramPath(CDebugUtils.java:658)
>   at org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core.CDebugUtils.verifyProgramPath(CDebugUtils.java:674)
>   at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.internal.LocalCDILaunchDelegate.runLocalApplication(LocalCDILaunchDelegate.java:85)
>   at org.eclipse.cdt.launch.internal.LocalCDILaunchDelegate.launch(LocalCDILaunchDelegate.java:71)
>   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
>   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
>   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
>   at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Workerindex.php.run(Worker.java:53)

With all this annoying problems I can't use eclipse anymore; I have to restart my pc in order to work again, but the problem rises again and again...
I use win 7 64 bit with mingw gnu 4.9.1. compiler

Please help me !

Comment: You don't happen to have the "C:\Users\Asus\workspace\Working\Debug" folder open in windows do you?  Or is "Working.exe" running in the background somewhere?

Comment: no; sometimes when i clean all projects it works well but the most of the time i encounter that annoying message and i can't do nothing but restart my pc...

Comment: Run ProcessExplorer while this is happening, and do a search for "working.exe" (or if that fails: "Debug"), and it will tell you what programs have those open.  Likely culprits are virus scanner and Windows search indexer.

Comment: where is this process explorer; please give me some details

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx.  Run it, press CTRL+F, and type "working.exe" and see what shows up.

Comment: @Mooing I hope this helps [link](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ziahcp.jpg)

Comment: Uh, "Working.exe" _is_ running in the background... three times!  At least two of these appear to be in the process of being debugged.  I would start stopping all debugging, and killing any "Working.exe" or "gdb.exe" that are still running.

Comment: Can you tell me the steps for debugging ? I did delete the working.exe  (any of it) and it seems to be working.  Thanks !

Comment: I don't know how Eclipse works.  When you hit run, and the program starts, how are you "stopping" it so that you can make more changes to the code?  _Are_ you stopping it?  It appears that you aren't.

Comment: I really don't know how to stop the program...i think it should stop itself. I hit a lot that "build 'debug' for projects" button...I am just editing when i'd like to expand my code. There is a button here called "Terminate" but i almost never click it...i click it when errors do appear on my console, usually when the information (the result) on the console goes to infinite with some results that i've miss write (like wrong loops --- >> streaming the result in continuum), but when i click "Terminate" it stops streaming. Should this be the stopping button ?

Comment: Yes, I suspect "Terminate" is probably the way to "kill" the program.  Alternatively, you can also kill most console programs by entering CTRL+C.

Comment: i am on windows 7 64 bit...ctrl+c stands for copying...

Comment: Sure.  Unless you're in a console window: http://blog.wpkg.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/winexe.png in which case it sends the "kill" signal.

Comment: @ Moing Hi again ! This guys from eclipse told me that i should enter in the debug perspective, there i'll also be able to see my working.exe program and just click "terminate" on it.

Comment: @moing [link](http://postimg.org/image/tmb6eni3z/) Please help me again with this stuff. That file is related to my panda antivirus program...it happens again "cleaning all projects has encountered a problem"; and i can't delete that file...and as long as i can't delete it, i can't run any program with eclipse(C/C++)...i need to restart my computer...should i turn off my panda antivirus while programming ? thanks !

Comment: man I love it when I'm right!  You can tell Panda to ignore your code folder: http://www.pandasecurity.com/homeusers/downloads/docs/product/help/is/2013/en/709.htm

Answer (score 0):

Probably the .metadata of your worksapce has been corrupted. Copying your project to a new workspace could get rid of the problem.

Comment: i did that & everywhere I put the workspace folder i have the same problem.

Comment: "everywhere I put the workspace folder" meaning did you copy the **existing** workspace folder to a different path or did you create a **new** workspace ?

Comment: yeah i've copied it to a different path and also configured it in eclipse and still...the same problem

Comment: If you copy the workspace to a different path, the corrupted .metadata folder will also get copied (because the .metadata will be inside the workspace folder) and so your problem will persist. Hence when you open eclipse and when it prompts you to choose a workspace, select a path and a folder where no workspace exists. Eclipse will create a **new** workspace for you (fresh .metadata will be generated). Now using Eclipse project export/import, export your project from old workspace and import it into new workspace.